# How to make sequential signup pages with Django allauth?

Tags: python, django

I currently have a single page signup form implemented with allauth

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    
    email = models.EmailField(_('Professional email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_("User Name"), blank=False, max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First Name"), null=True, max_length=255, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last Name"), null=True, max_length=255, default='')
    country = CountryField(_("Country of Practice"), blank_label='(Country of Practice)', blank = False, default='GB')
    terms = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('I have read and agree to the terms and conditions'), default=False)

 def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username}
        )

    objects = UserManager()
```

And this is the forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.UserCreationForm):

    error_message = forms.UserCreationForm.error_messages.update(
        {"duplicate_username": _("This username has already been taken.")}
    )

    username = CharField(label='User Name',
                        widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'}))

    class Meta(forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email',  'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'terms']
        field_order = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'terms']

    def clean_terms(self):
        is_filled = self.cleaned_data['terms']
        if not is_filled:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
        return is_filled  
    
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if self.instance.username == username:
            return username
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_username"]
        )
```

I would like however for the first sign up page to have a ‘next’ button at the bottom and then there would be a second page where the user input separate details (the data input here might vary based on the inputs in the first page). The Django ‘form tools’ form wizard seems well suite to this but I can’t work out how to integrate it with all auth

Any suggestions much appreciated